# MQTT connection in android application with cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, save, mqtt

Below code is my javascript code for MQTT communication. I have already checked the source code related to the MQTT part. It is working fine!

What I would like to do is
1) In `index.html`, when connection success from `mqtt_connect()` using username&password, page move `index.html` to `main.html`.

2) After than, in the `main.html`, if i push or click sensor/actuator/device setting button, then generate topic such as username/sensor, username/actuator, and username/device_setting. Using generated topic, I would like to be available to subscribe and to publish sensor/actuator/device related message.

Now, I am in a troble due to below.

I think 1) is working because the index.html page moves to main.html.
However, I can't subscribe and publish using topics due to the lost of MQTTconnection. It is because that username and password are not saved.

How could I fix this?

```js
var clickHandler = ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement ? "touchstart" : "click");
var connect = false;
var Password =null;
var User_id = null;
var first_conn = false;
var app = {
   
    initialize: function () {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
   
    bindEvents: function () {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
   
    onDeviceReady: function () {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    receivedEvent: function (id) {

        console.log('start');        
        var connectionBTN = document.getElementById("MQTT_connect");
        var disconnectBTN = document.getElementById("MQTT_disconnect");
        var subscribeBTN = document.getElementById("subscribe");
        var unsubscribeBTN = document.getElementById("unsubscribe");
        var publishBTN = document.getElementById("publish");
        var Sensor = document.getElementById("sensor");
        var Actuator = document.getElementById("actuator");
        var DeviceSetting = document.getElementById("device_setting");
        var subscribeBTN = document.getElementById("subscribe");        

        if (connectionBTN)
        {
            connectionBTN.addEventListener(clickHandler, mqtt_connect, false);
        }

        //document.getElementById("MQTT_connect").addEventListener(clickHandler, 

        function mqtt_connect() {
            console.log('click');
            var protocol = "tcp://"
            var addr = 'RANDOMLY_HIDE';
            var host = protocol + addr;
            var port_a = 'RANDOMLY_HIDE';
            cordova.plugins.CordovaMqTTPlugin.connect({
                url: host, //a public broker used for testing purposes only. Try using a self hosted broker for production.
                port: port_a,
                clientId: "mosquitto",
                connectionTimeout: 3000,
                username :document.getElementById("username").value,
                password :document.getElementById("password").value, 
                keepAlive:60,

                success: function (s) {
                    if (!first_conn) {
                        User_id = document.getElementById("password").value;
                        Password = document.getElementById("username").value;
                    }
                          connect = true;

                    console.log(JSON.stringify(s));
                    //document.getElementById("MQTT_connect").style.display = "none";
                    //document.getElementById("MQTT_disconnect").style.display = "block";
                    //document.getElementById("activity").innerHTML += "--> Success<connect success>: you are connected to, " + host + ":" + port_a + "<br>";
                    mqtt_connected();

                },

                error: function (e) {
                    console.log("connect fail");
                    connect = false;
                    alert(JSON.stringify(e));
                    console.log(e);
                },

                onConnectionLost: function () {
                    console.log("connect lost");
                    connect = false;
                    //document.getElementById("activity").innerHTML += "--> You got disconnected<connect error>";
                    //document.getElementById("MQTT_connect").style.display = "block";
                    //document.getElementById("MQTT_disconnect").style.display = "none";
                }

            })
        };

        function mqtt_connect1() {
            console.log('click');
            var protocol = "tcp://"
            var addr = 'RANDOMLY_HIDE;
            var host = protocol + addr;
            var port_a = 'RANDOMLY_HIDE';
            cordova.plugins.CordovaMqTTPlugin.connect({
                url: host, //a public broker used for testing purposes only. Try using a self hosted broker for production.
                port: port_a,
                clientId: "mosquitto",
                connectionTimeout: 3000,
                username: User_id,
                password: Password,
                keepAlive: 60,

                success: function (s) {
                    connect = true;
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(s));
                    //document.getElementById("MQTT_connect").style.display = "none";
                    //document.getElementById("MQTT_disconnect").style.display = "block";
                    //document.getElementById("activity").innerHTML += "--> Success<connect success>: you are connected to, " + host + ":" + port_a + "<br>";
                },

                error: function (e) {
                    console.log("connect fail");
                    connect = false;
                    alert(JSON.stringify(e));
                    console.log(e);
                },

                onConnectionLost: function () {
                    console.log("connect lost");
                    connect = false;
                    //document.getElementById("activity").innerHTML += "--> You got disconnected<connect error>";
                    //document.getElementById("MQTT_connect").style.display = "block";
                    //document.getElementById("MQTT_disconnect").style.display = "none";
                }

            })
        };
        function mqtt_connected() {


            console.log(connect);

                if (connect) {
                    console.log(connect);
                    location.href = "main.html";
                    connect = true;
                    first_conn = true;
                    mqtt_disconnect();
                }
                else {
                    mqtt_connect();
                }
 
        };

        if (disconnectBTN) {
            disconnectBTN.addEventListener(clickHandler, mqtt_disconnect, false);
        }

        // Disconnect
        function mqtt_disconnect() {
            cordova.plugins.CordovaMqTTPlugin.disconnect({
                success: function (s) {
                    console.log("disconnect");
                    connect = false;
                    //document.getElementById("MQTT_connect").style.display = "block";
                    //document.getElementById("MQTT_disconnect").style.display = "none";
                    //document.getElementById("activity").innerHTML += "--> Success<disconnect success>: you are now disconnected" + "<br>"
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    console.log("disconnect fail");
                    //document.getElementById("activity").innerHTML += "--> Error<disconnected>: something is wrong, " + e + "<br>";
                    //document.getElementById("MQTT_connect").style.display = "none";
                    //document.getElementById("MQTT_disconnect").style.display = "block";
                    //alert("err!! something is wrong. check the console")
                    console.log(e);
                }
            });
        };

        var sub_topic = null;
        var pub_topic = null;
        if (subscribeBTN) {


            subscribeBTN.addEventListener(clickHandler, mqtt_subscribe, false);

        }


        if (Sensor) {
            Sensor.addEventListener(clickHandler, mqtt_subscribe, false);
            sub_topic = 'Conv/' + User_id + '/Sensor/';
        }

        if (Actuator) {

            mqtt_connect1();
            Actuator.addEventListener(clickHandler, mqtt_subscribe, false);
            
            sub_topic = 'Conv/' + User_id + '/Actuator/';
        }

        function mqtt_subscribe(ev) {
            if (!connect) {

                mqtt_connect1();
                alert("First establish connection then try to subscribe");

                
            }
            else {

                console.log('connect : ' + connect);
                console.log('in the subscribe module');
                console.log('user_id : ' + User_id);

                console.log(sub_topic);
                cordova.plugins.CordovaMqTTPlugin.subscribe({
                    topic: sub_topic,
                    qos: 0,
                    success: function (s) {
                        console.log("subscribe success");
                        //document.getElementById("subscribe").style.display = "none";
                        //document.getElementById("unsubscribe").style.display = "block";
                        ////document.getElementById("activity_log").innerHTML += "--> Success<subscribe>: you are subscribed to the topic, " + sub_topic + "<br>"
                        //get your payload here
                        //Deprecated method
                        document.addEventListener(sub_topic, function (e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            //document.getElementById("activity_log").innerHTML += "--><subscribe> Payload for" + e.topic + " topic: " + JSON.stringify(e.payload) + "<br>"
                        });

                        cordova.plugins.CordovaMqTTPlugin.listen(sub_topic, function (payload, params, topic, topic_pattern) {
                            //params will be an empty object if topic pattern is NOT used. 
                            // document.getElementById("activity_log").innerHTML += "--><subscribe> Payload for" + topic + " topic: " + JSON.stringify(payload) + "<br>"
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        console.log("subscribe fail");
                        //document.getElementById("activity_log").innerHTML += "--> Error<subscribe>: something is wrong when subscribing to this topic, " + e + "<br>";
                        //document.getElementById("subscribe").style.display = "block";
                        //document.getElementById("unsubscribe").style.display = "none";
                        //alert("err!! something is wrong. check the console")
                        console.log(e);
                    },
                    onConnectionLost: function () {
                        console.log("connect lost hoho");
                        connect = false;
                        //document.getElementById("activity").innerHTML += "--> You got disconnected<connect error>";
                        //document.getElementById("MQTT_connect").style.display = "block";
                        //document.getElementById("MQTT_disconnect").style.display = "none";
                        console.log("connect lost");
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        // Unsubscribe




        if (unsubscribeBTN) {
            unsubscribeBTN.addEventListener(clickHandler, mqtt_unsubscribe, false);

        }


        function mqtt_unsubscribe(ev) {
            console.log('user_id : ' + User_id);
            cordova.plugins.CordovaMqTTPlugin.unsubscribe({
                topic: sub_topic,
                success: function (s) {
                    console.log("unsubscribe success");
                    //document.removeEventListener(sub_topic);
                    //document.getElementById("unsubscribe").style.display = "none";
                    //document.getElementById("subscribe").style.display = "block";
                    //document.getElementById("activity_log").innerHTML += "--> Success: you are unsubscribed to the topic, " + sub_topic + "<br>"
                    //sub_topic = "";
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    console.log("unsubscribe fail");
                    //document.getElementById("activity_log").innerHTML += "--> Error<unsubscribe>: something is wrong, " + e + "<br>";
                    //document.getElementById("subscribe").style.display = "block";
                    //document.getElementById("unsubscribe").style.display = "none";
                    //alert("err!! something is wrong. check the console")
                    console.log(e);
                }
            });
        };


        if (publishBTN) {

            mqtt_connect1();
            publishBTN.addEventListener(clickHandler, mqtt_publish, false);

        }

        if (DeviceSetting) {
            DeviceSetting.addEventListener(clickHandler, mqtt_publish, false);
            pub_topic = 'Conv/' + User_id + '/DevSetting/';
        }
        function mqtt_publish (ev) {
            if (!connect) {
                alert("First establish connection then try to publish")
            }
            else {
                var msg = document.getElementById("payload").value;
                console.log(msg);
                console.log(pub_topic);



                cordova.plugins.CordovaMqTTPlugin.publish({
                    topic: pub_topic,
                    payload: msg,
                    qos: 0,
                    retain: true,
                    success: function (s) {
                        console.log("publish success");
                        //document.getElementById("activity_log").innerHTML += "--> Success<publish>: you have published to the topic, " + pub_topic + "<br>";
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        console.log("publish fail");
                        //document.getElementById("activity_log").innerHTML += "--> Error<publish>: something is wrong, " + e + "<br>";
                        //alert("err!! something is wrong. check the console")
                        console.log(e);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    },
    append: function (id, s) {
        // it is just a string append function. Nothing to do with the MQTT functions
        var node = document.createElement("p");                 // Create a <li> node
        var textnode = document.createTextNode(s);         // Create a text node
        node.appendChild(textnode);                              // Append the text to <li>
        document.getElementById(id).appendChild(node);     // Append <li> to <ul> with id="myList"
    }
};

app.initialize();
```